# What are the EmailStatus and RegistrationStatus fields on the UserPart class used for in Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm working on a project that uses Orchard and I came across some logic in a custom `MembershipService` that checks a user's `EmailStatus` and `RegistrationStatus`

```
if (user.EmailStatus != UserStatus.Approved 
    || user.RegistrationStatus != UserStatus.Approved)
{
    return validateResult;
}
```

The trouble is that I can't figure out what these fields represent. I can hazard a guess that `EmailStatus` refers to email verification but I have no idea what the `RegistrationStatus` is. Can anyone explain what these fields represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Orchard you can enable a feature to require users verify their email, which is EmailStatus, as you guessed. If this feature is not enabled, their EmailStatus is automatically set to true.

There is also a status associated with users, the RegistrationStatus. This is used to disable a user (you can do this from /admin/users). It is also used when you enable the setting requiring manual approval of users. So when a user registers their RegistrationStatus is set to Pending and you must manually approve each registration before that user becomes Approved and can log in.